# How do I Identify duplicate and assign new ID?

Tags: python, pandas, biopython

I have a list of DNA oligos for  to order that have allot of duplicate sequences. However, I need them paired with the Identifier for which plasmid to to use them with.

In other words, I need this dataframe:

```
  Oligo_sequence   Plasmid
0 "ATG"           "Plasmid A"
1 "ATG"           "Plasmid B" 
2 "CAG"           "Plasmid C"
```

To become:

```
  Oligo_sequence    Plasmid
0 "ATG"           ["Plasmid A","Plasmid B"]
1 "CAG"           ["Plasmid C"]
```

I thought that a function similar to this would probably work. But I don't know how to identify the duplicates.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    plasmidlist = [row[1]]
    if duplicate == True: #Is their a dublicate function I can use? 
        plasmidlist.append(duplicaterow[1])
        drop(dublicaterow)

    df.at[row,'Plasmid']= plasmidlist
```

Comment: It's best to avoid using `.iterrows()`. Why do you want to do this, by the way?

Comment: try more use function like `groupby`, `apply` instead of `iterrow`: the first method: `df.groupby('Oligo_sequence')['Plasmid'].apply(list).reset_index()` ; the second method using lambda: `df.groupby('Oligo_sequence')['Plasmid'].apply(lambda x: ",".join(x).split(",")).reset_index()`

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby` and `agg` with list:

```
df.groupby('Oligo_sequence')['Plasmid'].agg(list)
```

Output:

```
"ATG"    ["Plasmid A", "Plasmid B"]
"CAG"                 ["Plasmid C"]
Name: Plasmid, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) with `.apply(list)`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Oligo_sequence':['ATG', 'ATG', 'CAG'], 'Plasmid':['Plasmid A', 'Plasmid B', 'Plasmid C']})

print(df.groupby('Oligo_sequence')['Plasmid'].apply(list).reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
  Oligo_sequence                 Plasmid
0            ATG  [Plasmid A, Plasmid B]
1            CAG             [Plasmid C]
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked beautifully

Answer (score 0):

If your parsing algorithm is working, I would use a dictionary structure to accomplish this task. You can check if an item exists in a list easily in Python:

```
     for each item in parent_list:
       if item is in plasmid_list:
          # do thing
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the string functions in Pandas if you are not so keen on lists: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html

```
Oligo_sequence=['ATG','ATG','CAG']
Plasmid = ['Plasmid A','Plasmid B', 'Plasmid C']
data = {'Oligo_sequence':Oligo_sequence,
        'Plasmid':Plasmid}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df


    Oligo_sequence  Plasmid
0       ATG        Plasmid A
1       ATG        Plasmid B
2       CAG        Plasmid C

(df
 .groupby('Oligo_sequence')
 .agg(lambda x: x['Plasmid'].str.cat(sep= ','))
 .reset_index()
)

    Oligo_sequence  Plasmid
 0      ATG        Plasmid A,Plasmid B
 1      CAG        Plasmid C
```